# window.opener is always null when using html native window.open

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Using the Native `window.open` function inside Electron results in opening a window but calling the variable `window.opener` on the opened window results in `null`. Would there be a reason why this is not working like in a normal chromium based browser? I read multiple posts about this issue. The latest post is dated late 2017 so I think it is already fixed but I cannot find how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using window.parent?  Or you can manually set window.opener on the return value of the window.open object.

Comment: window.parent is a reference to the opened window object (itself). when using the return value it is to late for me.

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately but I am using CEF now you could research it yourself. It's an great tool